# What standalone databases with GUI are available for Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, gui, database, sql

I have googled for this information and I am simply lost. I just need a simple, standalone and a single table database with GUI. I tried Libraoffice base, but it keeps giving me an error "S1000 java.lang.Null" and destroys all the record in the table. Then, I installed firebird and it doesn't have GUI to work with. I don't mind the terminal but it gets tedious after awhile having to enter commands in the terminal. Plus, when it comes to viewing your records in the terminal window, it won't be easy on your eyes and sometime it can be confusing. I even download a GUI razorsql for firebird but that is not FREE. All I am looking for is a simple database with GUI like liberaoffice base. Nothing fancy.

Answer (score 5):

Workbench together with [MySQL](http://mysql.com) are my favorite combination. Both are available in the [Ubuntu repositories](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/mysql-workbench/) but both can be install through their own [repository](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/) to get the latest versions. Both are also very well documented.

---

To install from the repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
```

---

Yes, both are not simple. But it will pay off when you get the hang of Workbench.

Example images:

- the localhost connecting is created by installing mysql. All you need to do is provide a password during install.

  [image]
- I created a database "discworld" with `create database discworld` and for creating a table in database "discworld":

  [image]
- insert and select table "wizards":

  [image]

It really is that easy. Most of the problems come from creating the more difficult SQL instructions. Not from mysql or workbench itself.

Comment: MySQL with INNOdb engine is not portable. Database moving only with export to SQL and import on other computer. MyISAM engine - simple create database and copy files.

Answer (score 1):

Mysql as database and phpmyadmin as frontend might be a well known combination.

Keep in mind this need a LAMP stack and is therefore not really standalone using a single app.

Comes with the big advantage of being well documented if it comes to examples,  tutorials  etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try use [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/). One file for database, SQL inside, used in many products, for example Chrome/Chromium, Firefox. On official site you can download simple command line utilites for database. I used it in online game Travian for mapping from command line :)

If you use any GUI, all compatible. I'm not sure whether it is possible a better simple database.

First GUI - [SQLite Studio](http://sqlitestudio.pl/), crossplatform.
[image: SQLite Studio interface]

Other - [addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) for Mozilla Firefox. Only Firefox needed.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please consider including links to these programs and some explanation to improve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Libreoffice Base is awful (as in unstable) when used as a stand alone solution (if you save data and queries in the same odb container). That being said the error you are referring to, is often a rsult of illegal null values in your database.

Libreoffice Base is great if combined with a real database and used as a graphical frontend. I use it with [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/) and never had any problems. Only problem is that when I switch from my work desktop to the laptop, I need to make an sql dump. But, this is only 5 minutes work and really worth the added stability and future proofness.

That said, other alternatives include [Kexi](http://www.kexi-project.org/) (though this was not stable enough when I tried it about 5 years ago) or [glom](http://www.glom.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page) (never tried that one)
 and a variety of sqlite solutions.

Comment: For installing MySQL, you really dont need to install the full LAMP stack. You can directly install by tying `sudo apt-get mysql-server mysql-client` . for the front end you can use MySQl Workbench/Administrator or Query tools depending on your OS version.

Comment: Sorry I missed you posted this as a coment @Nocturnalknight :-) (skimmed the answers for workbench). If you want to make your own answer PM me and Ill remove mine).